# React js, What is the best way to store redux state into local state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have reducer of `tables` and one of states are `mainTables`. I am using `react-dnd` to position these tables.

```
const initialState = {
 channel: null,
 errors: null,
 mainTables: [],
 takeaways: [],
 showMainTables: false,
 showTakeaways: false,
};
```

So now, my `tables_container` looks like below.

```
constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
   tables: []
 }
 this.fetchTables = this.fetchTables.bind(this);
 this.moveTable = this.moveTable.bind(this);
 this.saveTables = this.saveTables.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
 this.fetchTables()
}

fetchTables () {
  httpGet('/api/v1/tables')
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      tables: response.main_tables
    });
  });
};
```

`table_container` is a container of tables where user can move `table` to position it through `drag and drop`. Even though I have `mainTables` in reducer where stores all objects of `mainTable`, I use `fetchTables` to store `main_tables` to local state of `tables` because I want users to move tables for just testing and then if they like it they can store it by clicking `save` button. If they do not like it, they can just leave the page. So it does not have to change redux state all the time when user moves table. But with this method, there is a problem. As I use `fetchTable()` in `componentDidMount`, it does not update `this.state.tables` when a user creates a table. So to see just created table, user has to refresh pages..

So, what I want to ask is that 
1) How can I store redux state into local state (`this.state`) and update when a redux state is updated? is it possible? 
2) Can I call `fetchTables` when a new table is created? and how?

Thanks in advance..

----Edit add render method

```
render() {
if (this.props.tables.showMainTables ==true){
const { hideSourceOnDrag, connectDropTarget, number } = this.props;
const { tables } = this.state;
return connectDropTarget(
  <div style={styles}>
    {Object.keys(tables).map((key) => {
      const { x, y, number } = tables[key];
      return (
        <Table
          key={key}
          id={key}
          x={x}
          y={y}
          number={number}>

        </Table>
        );
    })}
    <button onClick={this.saveTables}>Save</button>
  </div>,
);

}

else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `contructor(props)` and `componentWillReceiveProps` to store global state to local state.

So in the view, I made `const mainTable = this.props.tables.mainTables` and pass `mainTable` to the `table_container`.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
  this.state = {
   tables: props.mainTables
 }
}
```

and made constructor like above.  And to get updated data and update it to local state, I used `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
if(this.state.tables.length != nextProps.mainTables.length){
  this.setState({tables: nextProps.mainTables})
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you will want to create a store e.g. TablesStore which will contain the initial state and any subsequent state after any external operations i.e. network call happens.

Your component will subscribe to it. And the store will let your component know every time the state changes. And then you can simply do something like `this.setState(TablesStore.getTablesState())`

Sending fetch requests from your component is very discouraged.
Also if you are looking for a complete architecture to base your app around, I don't think SO is the best place for that because that will easily become long enough for a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I do not understand your answer fully...  What I want to do is that to store `mainTables` of Initial state of `tables` to local component's state `this.state.tables`.. I pass `mainTables` to the local component and tried to `setState` in `componentDidMount` and `render` but both of them did not work.. so I am looking for how can I store `mainTables` to local component's state..

Comment: What I am able to get from this is that tables is a hash. So set it equal to `{}` instead of `[]` in your constructor and `this.props.tables.showMainTables` is set to false maybe?
Did u try and debug to see if this is the case?

Comment: you are using `this.props.tables.showMainTables ` instead of `this.state.tables.showMainTables ` how do you expect it to work? Are you passing tables object via props?

Comment: well, as in my question, I have `tables` reducer, which stores all states related to `tables`. And one of states is `showMainTables`. I have many table_types so I use `showMainTables` and `showTakeaways` to enable to see or not. These are not problems.. My question is that how can I get `mainTables` in the `tables` reducer and store `mainTables` as local state of the component. `mainTables` is an array, which has many objects of table.